# Hover Easing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

i want that when i hover the easing works, but it doesn't work :/ Is there any solution to solve it? The easing with time easeOutQuint 600 for example..

```
$(function(){
    $(".wrapholder").hover(function(){
        $(".wrap").stop().animate({top:"-320px"},{duration:300}, {easeOutQuint});
    }, function() {
        $(".wrap").stop().animate({top:"0px"},{duration:300}, {easeOutQuint});
    });
});
```

Comment: `{easeOutQuint}` is not the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have the jQuery UI library applied to your document, and instead of using {}, try wrapping the ease's name in quotations like so:

```
$(".wrapholder").hover(function(){
    $(".wrap").stop().animate({top:"-=320px"}, 1000, 'easeOutQuint');
}, function(){
    $(".wrap").stop().animate({top:"+=320px"}, 1000, 'easeOutQuint');
});
```

Here is a working example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/5W4Xj/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.  It should be:

```
$(".wrapholder").hover(function(){
    $(".wrap").stop().animate({top:"-320px"},{
        duration: 300,
        easing: 'easeOutQuint'
    });
}, function() {
    $(".wrap").stop().animate({top:"0px"},{
        duration: 300,
        easing:'easeOutQuint'
    });
});
```